# Unspecified return from a function

Tags: c, cs50

I've been teaching myself C through various sources. One of exercises I've found is this past year's cs50 problem sets ([found here](http://cdn.cs50.net/2012/fall/psets/1/hacker1.pdf#page=10) under the heading **Bad Credit**). Essentially, I've solved the problem but realized that I am performing the same step twice and perhaps could wrap that step inside of a function to be reused.

My problem is that I'm not sure how to define a return to an as yet unspecified array. Or, for that matter, if this is a good idea. I *think* that reusing the code would be a good thing if I could make it work, but I can't figure out how to do so.

The problem, as shown in the code below is taking a long number, separating each individual digit, and performing a bit of math to do a checksum. This is returned to `step1` in the code below. The `do/while` loop is doing the heavy lifting here, and what I would like to do is to do the same with elements in `step1` and return those into `step2` or any other variable for that matter.

```
long long num = 378282246310005;
int step1[10];
int step2[10];

do {
    int i = 0; 
    step1[i] = num % 10; // this returns to one array
    num /= 10;
    i++;
   } while (num != 0);
```

I realize this isn't that big a deal for this problem. I just decided that it would be good to know how to do it, if possible.

Comment: Pass a pointer to the array into the function.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `int i = 0;` needs to be outside the loop.

Comment: @Casey: Or you can make it as `static int i = 0;`???

Comment: @WedaPashi: And introduce global state? Why?

Comment: @GManNickG: Anyways he is going to need to make `i` a global `int` sir

Comment: @WedaPashi: No he's not, read the comment you first replied to. A regular old local variable is fine.

Comment: @GManNickG: Oh, got it sir! Local to the function, but outside the loop :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll take you through the steps.  Here's your code:

```
do {
    int i = 0; 
    step1[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
    i++;
} while (num != 0);
```

First, an error.  The `i` variable should be initialized and declared outside the loop, otherwise `i == 0` every single time you go through the loop.

```
int i = 0; 
do {
    step1[i] = num % 10;
    num /= 10;
    i++;
} while (num != 0);
```

This should be recognizable as the expanded version of a `for` loop, so:

```
for (int i = 0; num != 0; i++, num /= 10)
    step1[i] = num % 10;
// note: different for case num == 0
```

Then, if you want to turn it into a function,

```
void get_digits(int digits[], long long num) {
    for (int i = 0; num != 0; i++, num /= 10)
        digits[i] = num % 10;
}
```

A long story short, when you pass an array to a function in C, the array doesn't get copied so you can change the array inside the function and see those changes outside the function.  (Long version: when arrays are function parameters they decay into pointers.)

Final note: you will need 19 elements in the array, not 10.  So:

```
long long num = 378282246310005;
int step1[19];
get_digits(step1, num);
```

Comment: I believe I understand. You can specify the array inside the function, per your example: `get_digits(step2, step1[n])`.

Comment: Can we declare `i` as a `static int` here?

Comment: Arrays decay to pointers in most contexts; there's nothing special about their use as function arguments. (Array *parameter* declarations are adjusted to pointers, but that's a distinct rule.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: I was referring to array declarators in a function parameter list.  It's a bit tangential, and "decay" is a bit of an informal term anyway.

Comment: Note that the `for` loop is not equivalent to the `do … while` loop if an input of zero needs to be handled.  The `do … while` loop inserts a zero into the array; the `for` loop does not.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array by reference, like so:

```
//Number to checksum is num
//Array to store checksum is arr
//Maximal length of arr is n
void checksum(long long num, int arr[], int n){
  int i = 0; 
  do {
    arr[i] = num % 10; // this returns to one array
    num /= 10;
    i++;
    if(i==n) return; //break before we overflow array
  } while (num != 0);
}
```

Note that your code is potentially unsafe because you may end up writing to a part of the array beyond the memory you've allocated for it. That is, you define `int step1[10]` but may end up writing to `step[11]`.

Also, you stuck your `int i=0` inside of the loop. I assumed you wanted it outside.